# Don't understand why my Docker image is not being saved

Tags: docker

I'm confused about Docker to be honest. I have read a lot of the documentation but I don't understand what's going on with my image.

I pulled an Ubuntu image to my Mac, and executed docker `run -i -t` on it. Hooray! I'm in my image.

So I installed nodejs, npm, and the latest version of Python. Great!

But then — I leave the image and go back to the host terminal. I `docker run` it again, and find that all the changes I made have disappeared.

This reveals a fundamental ignorance of the nature and functions of Docker. Can I not make changes to my image and save it?

Comment: How did you save your image?

Comment: Docker run created a new running instance of container. You can see it by running docker ps -a command, you wll then see your running container. An output of docker ps -a contains container id (12-digit hex number). Use first 2 digits and start your old container, and then run docker exec (e.g. if container id is 7536867b5c4e), then run 'docker start 75 and then 'docker exec -it 75 /bin/bash' and you are back in your old container :)

Comment: Try going through the tutorial: [Creating our own images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/#/creating-our-own-images). If you have questions afterwards, come ask them and we'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not lose your container, it's just that it is stopped. When you run e.g.

```
docker run ubuntu
```

it is creating a new container from Ubuntu image (and that is a clean Ubuntu image without anything).
If you want to start your old image, first check its ID with

```
docker ps -a
```

In result you can see a list of containers, your old container is stopped.
Take container ID (12-digit hex number), and issue the following (let's assume that container ID is 7536867b5c4e):

```
docker start 75
```

and then run bash in it

```
docker attach -it 75 /bin/bash
```

and voila, your old container is up'n'running again with all additionally installed software on it.

Cheers

Comment: I believe you want a `docker attach -it 75 /bin/bash`. Run would try to create a new container from image "75".

Comment: Thanks! I'm going back to basics and reading the docs _properly_!

Comment: If the initial run command was to launch a bash, the start won't work you'll need to append -ia so the STDIN and STDOUT are attached.